# How to query nodes in a graph where the directly connected nodes to it satisfy a condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am interested in collecting nodes from my Neo4j graph using the following pattern

```
match (a)-[r:reln]->(b) return b
```

such that all the 'a' nodes for a given 'b' satisfy some condition like `a.prop='xxxx'`

Note: There could be multiple relationships of type: reln between a pair of 'a' and 'b' node.

I tried using the `all()` function but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you please share how you are using all() function? and what is the issue with that?

Comment: I was able to update my query to achieve the filtering using all function as below but not sure how to include a.prop in the return set  
    ```match (a)-[:reln]->(b) with collect(a) as pts, b
    where all(pt in pts where pt.prop = 'xxxx') 
    return b.prop```

Comment: Is it fixed value like 'xxxx' then instead of trying to get a.prop, you can just return that value along with b.prop.  Or you are looking for other values of 'a' as well?

Comment: I am interested in getting other properties of 'a' as well.

Comment: DO you want the list of these properties against each `b` node OR pairs of the b.prop, a.prop1, a.prop2, etc?

Comment: Would prefer list of these properties against each b node but can manage with the other approach as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [List comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension) to create the list of required properties from list `pts` as follows:

```
MATCH (a)-[:reln]->(b) 
WITH collect(a) as pts, b 
WHERE all(pt IN pts WHERE pt.prop = 'xxxx')  
RETURN b.prop, [ p IN pts | { prop1: p.prop1, prop2:p.prop2 }] AS a_props
```

If you wish to get pairs of properties of `a` against each `b` node:

```
MATCH (a)-[:reln]->(b) 
WITH collect(a) as pts, b 
WHERE all(pt IN pts WHERE pt.prop = 'xxxx') 
UNWIND pts AS a
RETURN b.prop, { prop1: a.prop1, prop2:a.prop2 } AS a_props
```

OR

```
MATCH (a)-[:reln]->(b) 
WITH collect(a) as pts, b 
WHERE all(pt IN pts WHERE pt.prop = 'xxxx') 
UNWIND pts as a
RETURN b.prop, a.prop, a.prop2
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the end nodes of all `reln` relationships in which the start node has a `prop` property equal to 'xxxx':

```
MATCH (a)-[:reln]->(b)
WHERE a.prop = 'xxxx'
RETURN a, b
```

If you want to return some individual properties of the start node, just specify them in the `RETURN` clause. For example:

```
...
RETURN a.prop, a.prop2, a.prop3, b
```

*NOTE: You should consider using [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) and possibly [indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) to help speed up your query.*

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear in my question. I am interested in set of nodes `b` where all the nodes connected to it with `reln` has a `prop` equal to `xxxx`. If any of the `a` node doesn't satisfy the condition, I want to filter that `b` from the result set. I was able to achieve that with query mentioned in the comment above but I am not able to access the properties of `a` in `RETURN` clause.

Comment: I have removed the labels and indexing from the query to keep it simple here.

Comment: In that case, take a look at @Raj's answer.